# Android get image full path

Tags: android

I am very new to android development and I am trying to get the image exif data selected from gallery. I am able to open the gallery and choose an image. But as I see online I need to get the image path which I am not able to get as

```
cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
```

is returning 0.

This is my code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(this,selectedImageUri);
    }
}
}
```

My function to get the real path is this

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    String result = null;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            context,
            contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if(cursor != null){
        int column_index =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return result;
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "*****"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner ""
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Am I missing something?

Comment: I which android version you are trying , please also specify model.

Comment: I added my android target version etc.

Comment: what do you need any real image path for?

Comment: I need to display the exif data of the image and maybe try to update them.  The links I read said that I should get the image path. the real one.

Comment: are you using `android.media.ExifInterface` or something else?

Comment: I haven't used anything yet. But plan to do so. exif = new ExifInterface(selectedImagePath); here I do need to send in the image path. Don't I?

Comment: then use `ExifInterface(FileDescriptor fileDescriptor)` or `ExifInterface(InputStream inputStream)` constructors, or even better see @CommonsWare answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But as I see online I need to get the image path

Wherever you are going "online" is incorrect. For starters, there is no "image path".

> My function to get the real path is this

That code has never been a good solution, has never worked well, and will fail for many `Uri` values.

> I am trying to get the image exif data selected from gallery

Step #1: Add the `support-exifinterface` library to your project

Step #2: Call `getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri)` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`

Step #3: Pass that `InputStream` to [the `android.support.media.ExifInterface` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream))

Step #4: Use that `ExifInterface` to get at your EXIF headers

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri){
        String filePath = "";
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

         // Split at colon, use second item in the array
         String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

         String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };     

         // where id is equal to             
         String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

         Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                                   column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

         int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
         }   
         cursor.close();
         return filePath;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
          String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
          String result = null;

          CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                  context, 
            contentUri, proj, null, null, null);        
          Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

          if(cursor != null){
           int column_index = 
             cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           result = cursor.getString(column_index);
          }
          return result;  
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri){
               String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
               Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
               int column_index
          = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
               cursor.moveToFirst();
               return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I have already tried this one. But thanks. :)

Comment: are you looking to get path of image from gallery {local}? and what does it mean ===But as I see online I need to get the image path which I am not able to get as